# How to merge multiple .csv with unique id in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, merge

I have 40 .csv files, all containing over 30 columns with the first column containing a unique ID variable. I would like to merge them all into a single data frame in R, doing a full outer join by the unique id variable.

Comment: Have you tried the answers posted in this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list

Comment: What exactly do you need? [A way to load your 40 csvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once) or a way to combine the dataframes obtained from loading csvs? They are many possible answers depending on how these dataframes are stored (in a list, in separate objects in your global environment, *etc*.). Could you please post a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example showing your researchs and your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Load your files into a list of tbls first. Then you could apply `purrr::reduce` which would sequentially combine two elements to one.

```r
library(purrr)
# instead of pasting you would join your tbls
purrr::reduce(list(1,2,3), ~paste("(", .x, "+", .y, ")"))
#> [1] "( ( 1 + 2 ) + 3 )"
purrr::reduce(list(1,2,3,4), ~paste("(", .x, "+", .y, ")"))
#> [1] "( ( ( 1 + 2 ) + 3 ) + 4 )"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>